# A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to use this code:

```
var controls = new[] { txtName, txtIdentityCard, txtMobile1 };
foreach (var control in controls.Where(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))) // error here in (e)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(control, "Please fill the required field");
}
```

to check if one of my textboxes is empty, but it gives the following error:

> A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a
>   local or parameter

Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As error clearly saying you cannot use `e` because it is already used somewhere else, like in your event handler or somewhere else:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Here for example
```

Try something else (`c`):

```
controls.Where(c => String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text)))
```

You also need to add this `errorProvider1.Clear();` below the `controls` declaration.

Comment: one thing else please .. the code works fine one by one ... i need to set the error for all the text boxes together ... and when one of them are filled so its error sign cleared

Comment: @a_fathy Just add this `errorProvider1.Clear();` below this `var controls = new[] { txtName, txtIdentityCard, txtMobile1 };` and above `foreach`.