# X cannot be declared in this scope + X cannot be used before it's declared

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following the Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-new-unity-hololens-app?tabs=azure-portal) to create a new HoloLens Unity app using Azure Spatial Anchors and the given code has some errors.

**The errors**
`'distance' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope` is the first encountered error. I tried to solve it by commenting `float` in front of `distance` but then I got `Cannot use local variable 'distance' before it is declared` + `Cannot infer the type of implicitly-typed deconstruction variable 'distance'.`

```
private bool IsAnchorNearby(Vector3 position, out GameObject anchorGameObject)
{
    anchorGameObject = null;

    if (_foundOrCreatedAnchorGameObjects.Count <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Iterate over existing anchor gameobjects to find the nearest
    var (distance, closestObject) = _foundOrCreatedAnchorGameObjects.Aggregate(
        new Tuple<float, GameObject>(Mathf.Infinity, null),
        (minPair, gameobject) =>
        {
            Vector3 gameObjectPosition = gameobject.transform.position;
            float distance = (position - gameObjectPosition).magnitude;
            return distance < minPair.Item1 ? new Tuple<float, GameObject>(distance, gameobject) : minPair;
        });

    if (distance <= 0.15f)
    {
        //Found an anchor within 15cm
        anchorGameObject = closestObject;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this tutorial's code ?

Comment: Use another name for `distance` in the lambda expression (`(minPair, gameobject) => {...}`) : `float d = ...; return d;`. The lambda expression is like another method inside the `IsAnchorNearby` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246472/a-local-or-parameter-named-e-cannot-be-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `distance` defined twice:

`var (distance, closestObject)`

and then:

`float distance = (position - gameObjectPosition).magnitude;`

Rename one or other.